# Differentiation using MATLAB

Tags: matlab, function, differentiation

I'm trying to write a small program using MATLAB in which I try to differentiate a function that I created inside a different function, but I keep getting errors.

My files are:

newton.m:

```
function [ y, iter ] = newton( f, fp, x0 )

    iter = 0;
    xprev = x0;
    x = xprev - f(xprev)/fp(xprev);

    iter = iter + 1;

    while abs(x-xprev) > eps*abs(x)
        xprev = x;
        x = x - f(x)/fp(x);
        iter = iter + 1;
        y = x;
    end
end
```

f.m:

```
function y = f(x)
    y = tan(x) - 2*x;
end
```

fp.m:

```
function y = fp(f)
    y = diff(f);
end
```

I'm running the following:

```
[y, iter] = newton(@f, @fp, 1.4)
```

and getting:

> Error using  /
>   Matrix dimensions must agree.
>
> Error in newton (line 6)
>       x = xprev - f(xprev)/fp(xprev);

When I'm checking the value of `y` in fp.m I keep getting `[]`.

Comment: The function `diff` returns the difference between elements in a vector. See <a href="http://se.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/diff.html">diff></a>. You need to get at least two values in when calling `fp`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to use `diff` to differentiate a function.  Out-of-the-box [`diff`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/diff.html) performs a difference operation between pairs of elements.  You don't want this.  Instead, make your `f` and `fp` as actual function handles.  First create the **symbolic** definition of your function `f`, then differentiate this symbolic representation using the symbolic version of `diff` (which you can just call with `diff` itself), then create a MATLAB function with [`matlabFunction`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/matlabfunction.html) out of this:

```
%// Define symbolic variable
syms x;

%// Define function symbolically
y = tan(x) - 2*x;

%// Define function handles (numerical) to the original and derivative
f = matlabFunction(y); 
fp = matlabFunction(diff(y));

%// Now call Newton's Method
[y, iter] = newton(f, fp, 1.4);
```

---

Take note that `f` and `fp` are already function handles.  That's what `matlabFunction` returns, so there isn't a need to create a handle via `@` as inputs into your Newton's Method function anymore.

Running this modification to your code, I get this for the root with the initial guess at `x = 1.4` and the amount of iterations it took:

```
>> format long g
>> y

y =

          1.16556118520721

>> iter

iter =

     8
```

---

## If the Symbolic Mathematics Toolbox is missing...

If, for some reason, you don't have the Symbolic Mathematics Toolbox, then what I suggested won't work.  As such, you don't have a choice but to use the discrete approximation of the derivative to get this to work.  However, we can still work with the code I wrote above, but `fp` will have to be defined differently.

If you recall, the definition of the derivative is such that:

[image]

To get this to work in the discrete case, you make `Δx` very small... something like `1e-10` for example.

As such, you would do this instead with anonymous functions:

```
%// Define function
f = @(x) tan(x) - 2*x;

%// Define derivative
h = 1e-10;
fp = @(x) (f(x + h) - f(x)) / h;

%// Now call Newton's Method
[y, iter] = newton(f, fp, 1.4);
```

With this, I get:

```
>> format long g;
>> y

y =

          1.16556118520721

>> iter

iter =

     8
```

I'd say that's pretty darn close!

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Tho I guess I'm missing something. Do I need to create the symbolic definition of my function f in the command windows or as a new 'm' file?

Comment: @Buzi No, you don't need to make a new M file for the original function and its derivative.  You create your function handles directly in the code.  Simply take the code I wrote above, put it in a new M file and run it.  I got it to run and that's how I got my answer.  BTW, when you get this to work, if you don't need any more help, consider accepting my answer to signify to the SO community that you don't need more help.  Good luck!

Comment: Should I call the new M file with a specific name? And sure, I will mark your answer as helpful :)

Comment: Yeah call it something like, `newtontest.m`, put the above code in this file, then run it.  You'll get the root and iterations when you're done... and thanks!

Comment: I keep getting an error: Error in newtontest (line 2)
syms x;

Comment: To use 'syms', you might need:
  syms - Symbolic Math Toolbox

Error in newtontest (line 2)
syms x;

Comment: oh boy... yeah you don't have that toolbox... so what I suggested won't work.  I'll have to reformulate so you work with the discrete approximation to the derivative.  You don't have a choice here.

Comment: Yes! Thank you very much!